# Why has LibreSSL stopped releasing windows binaries as of 2.6?

Tags: windows, binaryfiles, libressl

In this list:

https://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/LibreSSL/

there are no longer files `libressl-*-windows.zip` as of version 2.6.0.

Was an announcement made public about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a [message](https://marc.info/?l=libressl&m=149994708421035&w=2) sent to the [LibreSSL mailing list](https://www.libressl.org/mail.html) on 2017-07-03,

> Windows binaries are no longer included with LibreSSL 2.6.0.
>   The Windows build process has improved substantally, supporting
>   multiple compilers, environments, and ABIs. Because of slight variations
>   between these environments, and because it is so easy to build on
>   Windows in general, we are releasing source code only for all
>   platforms moving forward.